# How to retrieve IVsDebugger from external DTE for automation in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, ole, vsix

I am trying to write a VSIX for Visual Studio 2019 that controls multiple instances of the Visual Studio IDE. We are working on a networked project that requires some automation to perform testing of multiple users. In the past I would have used DTE in an external tool, but my understanding is that as of VS2017 the COM guids are no longer globally registered, so doing it within the IDE is the only way.

Regardless, I am trying to get the IVsDebugger so I can track events in the debugger. However, I am having no luck. I can get IVsDebugger2, 3, 4, 5 but not IVSDebugger. Here is the general flow of what I am doing:

```
void CaptureDebugger()
{
    DTE dte = GetDTE(GetRemoteProcessID());

    ServiceProvider sp = new     ServiceProvider((Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider)dte);
    IVsDebugger vsDebugger = sp.GetService(typeof(SVsShellDebugger)) as IVsDebugger;
    // vsDebugger is null!
    IVsDebugger2 vsDebugger2 = sp.GetService(typeof(SVsShellDebugger)) as IVsDebugger2;
    // vsDebugger2 is not null!


}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the DTE object from any devenv process.
/// </summary>
private static EnvDTE.DTE GetDTE(int processId)
{
    object runningObject = null;

    IBindCtx bindCtx = null;
    IRunningObjectTable rot = null;
    IEnumMoniker enumMonikers = null;

    try
    {
        Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(CreateBindCtx(reserved: 0, ppbc: out bindCtx));
        bindCtx.GetRunningObjectTable(out rot);
        rot.EnumRunning(out enumMonikers);

        IMoniker[] moniker = new IMoniker[1];
        IntPtr numberFetched = IntPtr.Zero;
        while (enumMonikers.Next(1, moniker, numberFetched) == 0)
        {
            IMoniker runningObjectMoniker = moniker[0];

            string name = null;

            try
            {
                if (runningObjectMoniker != null)
                {
                    runningObjectMoniker.GetDisplayName(bindCtx, null, out name);
                }
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                // Do nothing, there is something in the ROT that we do not have access to.
            }
            Regex monikerRegex = new Regex(@"!VisualStudio.DTE\.\d+\.\d+\:" + processId, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && monikerRegex.IsMatch(name))
            {
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(rot.GetObject(runningObjectMoniker, out runningObject));
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (enumMonikers != null)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(enumMonikers);

        if (rot != null)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rot);

        if (bindCtx != null)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(bindCtx);
    }

    return runningObject as EnvDTE.DTE;
}
```

What confuses me is I get get the local IVsDebugger via the call

```
var MYDEBUGGER = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsShellDebugger)) as IVsDebugger;
```

Which I see is using a GlobalService. I don't think there is an equivalent in the DTE I retrieve.

Any insight?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue as well (however in my case, I'm actually trying to retrieve the `IVsDebugger` *in proc* rather than what sounds like *out of proc*); after debugging into how `vsdebug!CDebugger::QueryInterface` works I determined the actual issue appears to be that **[the calling thread](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041213-00/?p=37043) in your application [needs to be STA](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090122-00/?p=19413).**

- When the calling thread in your application is MTA, while `vsdebug!CDebugger::QueryInterface` returns with `HRESULT` `0`
- This shortly gets turned into `0x80040155` (`REGDB_E_IIDNOTREG`) by OLE due to `CStdWrapper::GetPSFactory` failing to find a proxy DLL for this type
- This error in turn gets converted by `CRemoteUnknown::RemQueryInterface` to `0x80004002` (`E_NOINTERFACE`)
- Which is what is reported back to you if you try and `Marshal.QueryInterface` in C# to see what's going on directly.

If your program contains in-proc components that live inside the remote Visual Studio process (as mine does) you can retrieve and execute your operations against the `IVsDebugger` on the UI thread. Otherwise, you can potentially create a new `Thread` and call `thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)` on it prior to starting it

Comment: I abandoned this a long time ago but when I calculate the cumulative hours wasted pressing the buttons to do these tests manually I might just get back to trying it. Your explanation makes sense so I will try to figure it out in my use case.

Comment: I took a run at this and I am still getting a null reference to IVsDebugger even when using an STA thread. Are you trying to access a *different* DTE from the one VSIX is being hosted in?

Comment: My program consists of an external program remotely injecting a DLL into Visual Studio and then communicating with it over IPC, so while I don't have an "extension" per-se, my DLL should basically be functionally equivalent to any normal extension.

I can get a IVsDebugger simply by doing the following in-proc

System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    var apartment = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState();

    var debugger = (IVsDebugger) Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsShellDebugger));
});

Comment: Re-reading your question, it sounds to me like you're trying to get the IVsDebugger of Visual Studio instances from _out of proc_. I've confirmed that still doesn't work even if your out-of-proc thread is STA. As such, I think you would need to have some sort of in-proc mechanism you can IPC to to control the IVsDebugger that way

Comment: I think you are right - I will simply create a VSIX plugin and expose the plugin to the controller module using some form of IPC.