# Starting a process using Visual Studios' DTE with debugger attached

Tags: c#, visual-studio

We are developing an application "Configurator" that configures a job and then starts one or more applications "Processor"s that are processing these jobs.

Originally, there were no separate processes, and we were able to debug a single application with the debugger attached. Now, we have split the application into a "Configurator" and a "Processor" for several reasons.

As there are two application that we want to debug during development, this is a problem now, since Visual Studio attached the debugger only to the startup application. I know there is a feature for multiple startup projects, but this only works if the applications are started at the same time.Here, only our "Configurator" is started and the "Processor" is started at a later time using `Process.Start`.

So I thought this is not such a big problem and during development we can attach to the running DTE instance and attach the debugger using `DTE.Debugger.Attach()`. BUT: Visual Studio has its own process handling and a different `Process` structure, and I need to find the associated `VS Process` from the `real Process` using DTE.Debugger.LocalProcesses.

While this generally works, it is extremely slow iterating through `DTE.Debugger.LocalProcesses`.

So my question is if there is any chance of using the DTE to start a process directly, like `DTE.Debugger.StartProcess()`?

As far as I have seen, there is an `IVsDebugger` with the possibility to launch something, but I have no clue if I have access to it using the DTE and how to use it?

It seems that a similar question has been asked already here: [How to retrieve IVsDebugger from external DTE for automation in Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64626800/how-to-retrieve-ivsdebugger-from-external-dte-for-automation-in-visual-studio-20).

Comment: I feel like a simpler solution to this problem would just be to keep them separate if that's an option. Visual Studio has a field in the project properties to pass arguments to the program when debugging it. Just ensure the configurator passes the correct arguments and that they do what they're supposed to in the processor.

Comment: @Jesse: That would be the last option but is the least convenient. The Configurator creates the arguments. That would mean I have to start the Configurator first, save the arguments and the created config files. Close the Configurator, then put the commandline options in the project settings, switch project startup and then start the other application. That wouldn't be accepted by our developers.

Comment: Alright. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506882/can-not-debug-a-project-started-using-process-start) answer that may help and also had another idea. You could potentially build an abstraction layer between the two applications using a conditional reference to the Processor project from the Configurator project. You could then build it so if it's a debug build, it will call a method that just directly calls the main method of the Processor and passes the arguments. If it's a release build, have it start the process normally and pass the arguments.

Comment: Thanks. I think I saw some answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64626800/how-to-retrieve-ivsdebugger-from-external-dte-for-automation-in-visual-studio-20. I will try and check if it works. Thanks for helping.